# Databricks secret visible in cleartext

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-keyvault

I have a requirement that I need a secret when starting a cluster in databricks. And I found following way of providing the secret to my init script. https://docs.databricks.com/security/secrets/secrets.html#store-the-path-to-a-secret-in-an-environment-variable .
Now this worked fine, I was able to store the secret and provide it to init script. But when I open a web terminal and tried to print this secret, to my surprise it was printing this secret in cleartext format. What kind of secrets is it if it can be printed in cleartext by any user in workspaces. Now I'm not sure If I'm doing it incorrectly somewhere or is this thing common in databricks. Would appreciate any clarity on this.

Comment: Why aren't you using Azure's vault to store the secret instead?

Comment: I tried to use azure vault as a backend for databricks secrets, But I could not find a way to pass that to my init script. All the articles explain how secrets can be used in notebooks using dbutils API. Do you know a way, how can I those secrets stored in the vault to my init script?

Comment: Have you looked in [their docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes#azure-key-vault-backed-scopes)? Usually you can pull in the secret through the REST API or the CLI utils they provide.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I tried this. But I'm not sure how do I provide bearer token needed for request safely to our init script. It can't be hardcoded in script, we can't store it in an environment variable. How else can we provide this bearer token to the rest api request in init script?